# When trying to update a video snippet I always get a Forbidden response

Tags: api, youtube

I am creating an app to update my videos through the youtube api v3.

I have set up everything correctly according to the documentation. Have the API key and OAuth credentials. But everytime I try to update (in my app or in the API test page) I get this json response:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Forbidden". Details: "[{'message': 'Forbidden', 'domain': 'youtube.video', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">

I'm getting so frustrated, this specific error only shows "Forbidden" with no extra info.

Does anyone knows what it could be? Thank you

X